Bulk modulus of metals at room temperature
Imagine a sample of solid metal at room temperature. It exhibits resistance to compression which is expressed as its bulk modulus. Part of this resistance originates from a treatment of the delocalized valence electrons as an electron gas which resists compression because of degeneracy pressure and part of it is due simply to electrostatic forces between adjacent atoms and that electron gas. Here are my questions:

At room temperature, what are the relative contributions of these two different mechanisms to the bulk modulus we measure in the lab? and

If we exert negative (i.e., tensile) pressure on that same sample, one would think that the degeneracy pressure contribution would lessen since we are no longer trying to force electrons into the same quantum energy level- which would leave the electrostatic mechanism the dominant one for metals in tension. Is this true- that is, do we measure different values for the bulk modulus in triaxial compression versus expansion?



I guess I see your two separate things as two sides of one coin. Change the nuclei spacing and the band structure changes. As for the last bit, for small deformation the potential will be parabolic and the bulk modulus is the same on compression vs tension.

@jon custer, thanks for that. is that parabolic potential then due just to electrostatics for interatomic spacing deltas ~small? I'm trying to square this with what I learned in my materials science program from college days- that for "engineering" values of applied stress (as in for example ordinary beams, cable, & tensile testing) electrostatics is sufficient to model the moduli and band structure effects can be neglected?

The nuclei in a stable crystal are sitting in a local potential minimum, and the overall potential is a joint creation of the nuclei and the electronic structure. To first order a minimum is parabolic. At larger displacements higher order terms become important. Now it is often useful to consider the electrons as a gas (Drude model, etc.) but then one is assuming small, if any, atomic displacements.

Also discussed in Can Hooke’s Law be derived?

@Chemomechanics yes yes!! thanks for the older reference!

Dyson & Lenard's "Stability of matter" is of course interesting related background. I don't know whether it or subsequent work provides the tools to answer subquestion (1) in terms of a relative contribution of effects.
